# I don't know how to implement math.round() or any other solution to get ##.## in JTextField

Tags: java, string, swing, jfreechart, jtextfield

I am displaying average in `JTextField` and I want to round it up to two decimal places to use my code above, to create `BarChart` using `JFreeChart`. I have seen many tutorials about that, but I don't know how to implement any of it in my code.

That is my list:

```
List<Double> light = new ArrayList<Double>();
for (Measurement measurement : readMeasurements) {
light.add(Double.parseDouble(measurement.getLight()));}

double averageLight = Utils.calculateAverage(light);
textLight.setText(averageLight+" ...");
```

That is my `Utils` that calculate average:

```
public static double calculateAverage(List<Double> list){
        double av=0;
        double sum=0;

        for(double value : list){
            sum+=value;

        }
        av = sum/list.size();
        return av;
    }
```

With that I get in textfiled output like `##.################`.

And here is part of cod`e that creates BarChart using JFreeChart. It works when in`JTextField`output is ##.##`:

```
String temperature = textTemp.getText();
String light = textLight.getText();
String vcc = textVcc.getText();

DefaultCategoryDataset dataset = new DefaultCategoryDataset();
dataset.setValue(new Double (temperature), "Measurements", "Temperature");
dataset.setValue(new Double (light), "Measurements", "Light");
dataset.setValue(new Double (vcc), "Measurements", "Vcc");
```

How can I make any changes to that code to make an output in `JTextField` like `##.##`?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
textLight.setText(String.format("%.2f", averageLight));
```

The `"%.2f"` is a format string, and means "format an argument as a floating point number with two decimal places".  For more detail on what characters you can use in one of those, and what they each mean, refer to http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Formatter.html

Comment: After implementing your advice my STAX Parser is displaying XML into Textarea, but it's stops showing/calculating average in JTextField. Any advice? Thank you for a fast reply! (f != java.lang.String)

Comment: You'll still have to call `calculateAverage`.  Are you doing that?

Comment: Ye I have figured it out after a while ty!

Answer (score 2):

You can use a [decimal formatter](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/text/DecimalFormat.html) for the specified pattern.

```
DecimalFormat df = new DecimalFormat("#,##0.00");
textLight.setText(df.format(averageLight));
```

If you need to read the value from the textfield you can use the same formatter to *parse* text value. So, you text value becomes readable and writable. Take care about handling `ParseException` and the locale specific symbols.

Answer (score 0):

[NumberFormat](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/text/NumberFormat.html) is probably better than String.format for this purpose:

```
NumberFormat nf = NumberFormat.getInstance();
nf.setRoundingMode(RoundingMode.HALF_UP);
nf.setMaximumFractionDigits(2);
textLight.setText(String.format(nf.format(averageLight));
```

Do leave a comment if you should have further problems.

Comment: With your code Sir I am not getting reading on the last out of 3 JTextBoxes. But Roman C works great! Thank you for a such reply all you guys!